# I have a for loop. it doesnt work on hardhat but works on mumbai testnet

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink

I have basic chainlink vrf contract.Trying to get 12 random numbers.I want to save those random numbers in another array.
I define an array called output. in fulfillRandomWords function, simple assign every element to element. But it stuck 8. of element like in the pic.When i comment out for loop and check the

```
s_requests[_requestId].randomWords
```

i can see all the random numbers.

I also deployed to mumbai testnet. i can get output array on mumbai.
My contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

/**@title A sample Chainlink VRF Contract
 * @author Furkan Sezal
 * @notice This contract is for creating getting 12 random number without repeat
 * @dev This implements the Chainlink VRF Version 2
 */

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ConfirmedOwner {
    /* Type declarations */

    /* State variables */
    address payable[] private s_players;

    // Chainlink VRF Variables
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_keyHash;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 12;
    uint256[12] public output;

    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */

    struct RequestStatus {
        bool fulfilled; // whether the request has been successfully fulfilled
        bool exists; // whether a requestId exists
        uint256[] randomWords;
    }
    // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    uint256 public test;

    /* Events */
    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestId, uint256[] randomWords);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        bytes32 keyHash,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_keyHash = keyHash;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    }

    // Assumes the subscription is funded sufficiently.
    function requestRandomWords()
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        // Will revert if subscription is not set and funded.
        requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_keyHash,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            exists: true,
            fulfilled: false
        });
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, NUM_WORDS);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;

        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            output[i] = _randomWords[i];
            console.log(i);
        }

        emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, _randomWords);
    }
     /* pure and view functions */

    function getOutput() public view returns (uint256[12] memory) {
        return output;
    }


}
```

Mock Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol";
```

My test file:

```
const { ethers, deployments, getNamedAccounts, network } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-config");
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("Lottery unit tests", async () => {
      let lottery, vrfCoordinatorMock, deployer;
      const chainId = network.config.chainId;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        // before every test deploy our contracts
        // get the deployer account from getNamedAccount ( which come from hardhat-config)
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        //console.log(deployer);
        // deploy all our contracts
        await deployments.fixture("all");
        lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery", deployer);
        vrfCoordinatorMock = await ethers.getContract(
          "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
          deployer
        );
      });

      describe("fulfillRandomWords", async () => {
        it("Get 12 random number", async () => {
          // all this promise think do : listen to RequestFulfilled event
          const tx = await lottery.requestRandomWords();
          const tx_receipt = await tx.wait(1);
          await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            lottery.once("RequestFulfilled", async () => {
              console.log("Found the event");
              try {
                resolve();
              } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
              }
            });

            await vrfCoordinatorMock.fulfillRandomWords(
              tx_receipt.events[1].args.requestId,
              lottery.address
            );
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

[image]